# segfault in python with C extension and threads

Tags: python, c, multithreading

I am writing a C extension to Python that makes use of native pthreads on Linux outside of the cpython interpreter. I read up on the GIL and AFAIK I'm doing everything according to the python 2.7 documentation.

And, as long as I do not start additional python threads, all is well. But, I wanted to make a unittest script which starts the server that I need to talk to in a python thread. As soon as I do this, the program crashes, indicating to me that I'm doing something wrong with the GIL. This is the GDB backtrace:

```
Core was generated by `/usr/bin/python ./test.py'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004cc69f in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004cc69f in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#1  0x00000000004e4518 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000004ccd09 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#3  0x00000000004c996a in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#4  0x00000000004c996a in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#5  0x00000000004e4518 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000000502ab8 in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000004d0f2b in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#8  0x00000000005bc202 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f3198b86064 in start_thread (arg=0x7f3196c91700) at pthread_create.c:309
#10 0x00007f3197f9862d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

The thread is pretty simple:

```
command = [server_path, '-s', sockpath]
log.info("command is %s", command)

def runserver(command):
    log.info("in runserver")
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(command,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                            shell=False)
    log.info("pipe open")
    line = pipe.stdout.readline()
    while line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        # Handle unicode
        try:
            line = line.decode('utf8', 'replace')
            log.info(line)
        except UnicodeDecodeError, err:
            log.error("failed to handle line: %s", str(err))
        line = pipe.stdout.readline()

server_thread = threading.Thread(target=runserver, kwargs={'command': command})
server_thread.daemon = True
log.info("starting server thread")
server_thread.start()
```

And this is the initialization from my C extension.

```
// Our module entry point.
PyMODINIT_FUNC initlibinipy(void) {
    PyObject *m;

    m = Py_InitModule3("libinipy", libinipy_methods, "FIXME: put docstring here");
    if (m == NULL)
        return;

    /*
     * Create our exception types. IniDbError is the base class of all exceptions in
     * this library.
     */
    IniDbError = PyErr_NewException("libinipy.IniDbError", NULL, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(IniDbError);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "IniDbError", IniDbError);

    IniDbConnectError = PyErr_NewException("libinipy.IniDbConnectError", IniDbError, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(IniDbConnectError);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "IniDbConnectError", IniDbConnectError);

    IniDbFlushError = PyErr_NewException("libinipy.IniDbFlushError", IniDbError, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(IniDbFlushError);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "IniDbFlushError", IniDbFlushError);

    IniDbBadParamError = PyErr_NewException("libinipy.IniDbBadParamError", IniDbError, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(IniDbBadParamError);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "IniDbBadParamError", IniDbBadParamError);

    IniDbBadHandleError = PyErr_NewException("libinipy.IniDbBadHandleError", IniDbError, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(IniDbBadHandleError);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "IniDbBadHandleError", IniDbBadHandleError);

    IniDbFileNotFoundError = PyErr_NewException("libinipy.IniDbFileNotFoundError", IniDbError, NULL);
    Py_INCREF(IniDbFileNotFoundError);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "IniDbFileNotFoundError", IniDbFileNotFoundError);

    // Initialize mutexes.
    pthread_mutex_init(&monitor_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&section_list_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&entry_list_mutex, NULL);
}
```

My understanding is that the interpreter is already holding the GIL on entry, so there's no need to acquire it here. Note that the code is crashing immediately, without running any of my unit tests, but it crashes sporadically. Sometimes it executes without crashing.

So apparently simply loading my module is sufficient to cause this sporadic crash, so I'm obviously doing something wrong here. Help appreciated. Thanks.